# How can I make sure I take the screenshot of a specific window using Perl's Imager::Screenshot?

Tags: windows, perl, internet-explorer, browser

I use [Imager::Screenshot](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Imager%3a%3aScreenshot) in my Perl code and it does work and takes the screenshot.

Now, every time the browser opens in different position, meaning starting x and y positions might not be the same.

Is there a way to screenshot starting from the browser instead of the desktop starting position.

And if not (kind of off topic from programming) is there a way to set the browser open only in full size, no matter what program its opened from. Opened by user when clicked on the icon, or opened by Perl using [Win32::OLE](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Win32%3a%3aOLE) module.

Comment: Which browser(s) - I guess you will need to check the command line flags for the relevant browser.

Comment: It looks like `Imager::Screenshot` will capture a window given a window handle.  If you can find another module to get the window handle from the window title (or other identifying information) you should be able to capture just the window you want.

Comment: It also looks like you can capture the active window using `screenshot(hwnd => 'active')` so if you can ensure the browser window is the active window you should be able to capture it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [Win32::GuiTest::FindWindowLike](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Win32%3a%3aGuiTest) to find the window handle associated with the browser and specify that to `screenshot`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict; use warnings;
use Const::Fast;
use Imager;
use Imager::Screenshot qw( screenshot );
use Win32::GuiTest qw( FindWindowLike SetForegroundWindow );

const my $TYPE => 'bmp';

my @windows = FindWindowLike(0,
    '(?:Mozilla Firefox)|(?:Internet Explorer)|(?:Opera)'
);

for my $hwnd (@windows) {
    warn "$hwnd\n";
    SetForegroundWindow $hwnd;
    sleep 1;
    my $img = screenshot(hwnd => $hwnd, decor => 1);
    die Imager->errstr unless $img;

    $img->write(file => "$hwnd.$TYPE", type => $TYPE)
        or die $img->errstr;
}
```

The code above will take separate screenshots for the overall IE window and the child window that holds the current tab. If you are only interested in top level IE windows, you'd want to use `my @windows = FindWindowLike(0, 'Internet Explorer', '^IEFrame');`

In addition, if you have opened an ["InternetExplorer.Application"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752084%28v=vs.85%29) window using `Win32::OLE`, you can access the object's [Top](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752079%28v=vs.85%29), [Height](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752055%28v=vs.85%29), and [Width](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752083%28v=vs.85%29) properties to determine its location and area. In addition, you can get its [HWND](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb268219%28v=vs.85%29) so that you can set it as the foreground window.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict; use warnings;
use Const::Fast;
use Imager;
use Imager::Screenshot qw( screenshot );
use Win32::GuiTest qw( SetForegroundWindow );
use Win32::OLE;
$Win32::OLE::Warn = 3;

const my $TYPE => 'bmp';

const my $READYSTATE_COMPLETE => 4;

my $browser = Win32::OLE->new("InternetExplorer.Application");
$browser->Navigate('http://www.example.com/');

sleep 1 while $browser->{ReadyState} != $READYSTATE_COMPLETE;
$browser->{Visible} = 1;

my $hwnd = $browser->{HWND};
SetForegroundWindow $hwnd;
sleep 1;

my $img = screenshot(hwnd => $hwnd, decor => 1) or die Imager->errstr;

my $title = $browser->{LocationName};
$browser->Quit;

$title =~ s/[^A-Za-z0-9_-]/-/g;
$img->write(file => "$title.$TYPE", type => $TYPE) or die $img->errstr;
```

Alternatively, [using OLE events](http://blog.nu42.com/2012/06/using-win32ole-with-events-to-capture.html):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict; use warnings;
use feature 'say';
use Const::Fast;
use Imager;
use Imager::Screenshot qw( screenshot );
use Win32::GuiTest qw( SetForegroundWindow );
use Win32::OLE qw(EVENTS valof);
$Win32::OLE::Warn = 3;

const my $TYPE => 'bmp';
const my $READYSTATE_COMPLETE => 4;

my ($URL) = @ARGV;
die "Need URL\n" unless defined $URL;

my $browser = Win32::OLE->new(
    "InternetExplorer.Application", sub { $_[0]->Quit }
);
Win32::OLE->WithEvents($browser, \&Event, 'DWebBrowserEvents2');

$browser->{Visible} = 1;
$browser->Navigate2($URL);

Win32::OLE->MessageLoop;
Win32::OLE->SpinMessageLoop;

$browser->Quit;
sleep 3;

sub Event {
    my ($browser, $event, @argv) = @_;
    say $event;

    if ($event eq 'DocumentComplete') {
        $browser->{ReadyState} == $READYSTATE_COMPLETE
            or return;

        my $hwnd = $browser->{HWND};
        SetForegroundWindow $hwnd;

        my $img = screenshot(hwnd => $hwnd, decor => 1)
            or die Imager->errstr;

        my $url = valof( $argv[1] );
        $url =~ s{^https?://}{};
        $url =~ s{[^A-Za-z0-9_-]}{-}g;

        $img->write(file => "$url.$TYPE", type => $TYPE)
            or die $img->errstr;

        Win32::OLE->QuitMessageLoop;
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: is it possible to make the window be maximized when you open with `Win32::OLE->new()`?

Comment: You can send [WM_SYSCOMMAND with SC_MAXIMIZE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646360%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to `$hwnd` using `Win32::GuiTest::SendMessage` or use `Win32::GuiTest::GetScreenRes` to determine the screen resolution and set the `Top`, `Height` and `Width` attributes of `$browser` before making it visible.

Comment: For this program I don't need to determine, just set it maximized straight without getting width/height

Comment: You're not even going to try, are you? See [On Windows, how can I maximize a window created using Win32::OLE?](http://blog.nu42.com/2012/06/on-windows-how-can-i-maximize-window.html)

Comment: I am going to try, I am not at home, the program is at home to work on. I guarantee I am going to try it :)